# npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: node.js, npm, error-handling, custom-error-handling

I have windows 10 laptop. Node.js version is v.16.15.1 and npm version is 8.13.2. I run 'npm install' in terminal and it gives me erors:

```
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\h\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-07T08_33_12_931Z-debug-0.log
```

next i open debug-0.log:

```
45 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
45 verbose stack     at C:\Users\h\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:285:30
48 verbose node v16.15.1
49 verbose npm  v8.13.2
50 error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
51 verbose exit 1
52 timing npm Completed in 213ms
53 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1657134370529
54 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1657134370538
55 verbose code 1
56 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
56 error     C:\Users\h\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-06T19_06_10_353Z-debug-0.log
```